# Does twitter button shows tweets or tweets+retweets?

Tags: twitter

- Will the number on tweet
  button on my site increase if someone
  on twitter, without even opening the
  link, shares the url?
- Can **one user** make tweet button **count go from 0 to 2** in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The count should +1 for every tweet or retweet that contains the link.
- If a single user tweets the same link twice the count should +2.

Keep in mind though that Twitter has such a high volume of tweets that tweet button counts will likely be off by a %. Sometimes the count is cached as well resulting in delays between tweets containing the link and the count increasing.

Comment: Could someone verify this please? Any documentation for this?

Comment: This is not explicitly documented anywhere. It is based on my knowledge of how Twitter handles tweets and posts from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/twitter-development-talk. You are more then welcome to test and verify yourself though.